# É errado chamar algum membro que você sabe que pode ajudar na solução de um problema?

Tags: debate

É errado chamar algum membro que você sabe que pode ajudar na solução de um problema? muitas das vezes algumas perguntas rapidamente vão para a parte debaixo da pilha de perguntas recentes o que pode diminuir a chances dela ser respondida, ou é um final de semana e geralmente tem menos membros ativos.
Chamar seria comentar usando @usuario nos comentários da pergunta ou no chat.

Comment: Chamar o usuário nos comentários da pergunta não vai funcionar, e no chat só vai funcionar se o usuário tiver acessado recentemente. Mas a dúvida é interessante.

Comment: Podes sempre fazer um _edit_ à pergunta para ela aparecer a tab de "ativas" e/ou dar uma recompensa.

Comment: Vivem me chamando pra resolver umas coisas cabeludas. Quando não conseguem me chamar na própria pergunta, me chamam no chat. Não vejo problema algum.

Comment: Imaginei que os os outros membros iriam me achar _Folgado_ por causa disso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sem dúvida ficar sempre chamando a mesma pessoa para ajudar em perguntas pode se tornar inconveniente, porém a opção "compartilhar" que aparece abaixo da pergunta é indicada para se referenciar a pergunta, e assim publica-la nos mais diversos locais, em especial nas redes sociais.